# HttpContext.Current.Response.Write is breaking the page layout

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to inject a script tag containing a JSON into the **HttpContext.Current.Response.Output** of a asp.net MVC request using React SSR.

I need to do that because I have to get some information in my context request and then put it into the HTML source for SEO purposes.

I've been trying to add this script tag to the output by using HttpContext.Current.Response.Write or HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write (or WriteLine) but when I do the resultant layout is resized and some widgets lose their size and alignment.

Does anyone have any tip about how to inject this **big** script tag without breaking the final layout?

Comment: Yeah - don't use Response.Write to modify the response in an ASP.NET MVC application. You don't have proper control over where the content gets inserted if you do that, thus making it likely your page will be malformed. If you need to put some content on your MVC page, that's what a View is for. Did you try inserting this script tag into your View (.cshtml)?

Comment: Actually the pages are generated dynamically, There isn't a cshtml file for them unfortunately.... It is a kind of blackbox CMS system.

Comment: Okay - so the body of your HTTP response is generated not through the usual ASP.NET MVC system - how exactly do you normally get it into the response? You need to put the script tag in at the proper spot in the body, but we have no access to your system, we don't know how the site is put together. You're going to need to fully describe your situation so we can help.

Comment: Hey Mason, thank you for your availability to help me. I have overcome this situation by overwriting the method write and passing it as a Filter for httpContext.current.response.filter
So for this specific request, the system uses my custom write method to build the response....